# FNR==NR match is thwarted by evil data

Tags: awk, compare, union

I do not know what is going on but I cannot get the this to work:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}$0 in a{print $0}' file2 file1
```

I have two files, one with 150 three letter codes and another with 700 three letter codes. No, I am not posting all 850 codes on this board. But I have stripped them of white spaces, removed all blanks, assured line continuity with no avail. I've found the code in several places, cut and paste and nothing. I can make my own small files up and it works. What is going on to cause this stalwart of sorting to fail? It's been a couple of hours. I'm going to punch the wall some....

Comment: Are both files from the same source? Could one have unix line endings and the other have DOS line endings, e.g.?  Do you get zero output? Or are some codes output while others that should also be are not?

Comment: Pipe the first three lines of each file through `od -c` or a hex dump program of your choosing (`sed 3q file2 | od -c`). Look to see if there is a difference in the line endings.  What you show should work — you say it does work when you create the files locally.  That suggests that you are trying to process files created remotely, and that they line endings were not mapped when the files were transferred.  (This is what [jas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2229272/jas) [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622836/fnr-nr-match-is-thwarted-by-evil-data#comment51194828_31622836) too.)

Comment: I thought about the whole DOS and other endings @jas. Right with you. Jonathan Leffler, I ran the sed/od combo and here is what I get:

Comment: cosmo@cosmo:~/work/new$ sed 3q file1 | od -c
0000000   A   F   R  \r  \n   A   R   C  \r  \n   A   R   D  \r  \n
0000017
cosmo@cosmo:~/work/new$ sed 3q file2 | od -c
0000000   A   B   E  \n   A   B   T  \n   A   B   W  \n
0000014

Comment: One has a \r while the uses new lines only. How might I sync them up? And thank you both for an excellent idea.

Comment: I just found the power of "tr"  Awesome! Thanks so much!

Comment: `tr`? Just set RS between files: `awk 'whatever' RS='\r\n' file1 RS='\n' file2` or whatever you need.